# Git. PHPStorm. Переключение между доработками

Tags: git, phpstorm

Ситуация: работаю в PHPStorm, в git ветка master. Создаю в гите ветку test1. Работаю в ней, пишу какой-то код. Пришла срочная задача по другой теме, но в рамках этого же сайта. НЕ создаю коммит в ветке test1, переключаюсь на master. И в ветке master вижу все изменения, которые я делал в ветке test1. Почему так? Как можно сделать так, чтобы я работал в одной ветке (test1), потом переключился в мастер и в нем был бы только тот код, который был на момент **создания** ветки test1? Потом из ветки master создал другую ветку, допустим test2, и уже работал бы в ветке test2. Потом пришла третья срочная задача, переключаюсь на master, создаю ветку test3, работаю в ней. Но чтобы в этих ветках test1, test2, test3 не было изменений кода от других веток. При этом коммиты не создаю. И при этом чтобы можно было переключиться на любую из этих веток и продолжить работу. Как это сделать?

Comment: пока не сделан коммит, изменения не принадлежат никакой ветке

Comment: Есть разные варианты: `git stash` и `git worktree` в самой системе контроля версий. Можно, конечно, создавать отдельные копии репозитория или ещё как-то, но это того не стоит.

Comment: Добавлю, что `git worktree` — очень мощная штука, можно к ней относиться как к `git stash`-на-стероидах. Проблема, как выяснилось и стало для меня сюрпризом, не все понимают как это надо готовить и какие преимущества это даёт. Тем не менее я рекомендую именно `git worktree` использовать для разработки фич и `git stash` для случаев, когда реально надо _быстро исправить один пробел в одной строке одного файла_.

Comment: @0andriy так вы напишите **ответ**, а не комментарий. Напишите что это, как пользоваться и в чём профит. Глядишь, будет каким-то топовым ответом и всем поможет. А то сейчас выглядит как "делай так, это круто". А что круто, почему круто, с чего это круто - не ясно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать `git stash` перед тем как *срочно переключиться на другую ветку*. **[git stash](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash)** Это просто спрячет ваши изменения без коммита, к которым можно будет потом вернуться и достать их из того места, куда они были спрятаны и продолжить работу

> С помощью команды git stash можно спрятать эти изменения. Ваши
> изменения помещаются в отдельное хранилище — в стек, а вы можете
> спокойно переключиться на другую ветку.
>
> Всё, что вы прячете с помощью git stash, попадает в отдельный список.
> Затем вы можете извлекать оттуда то, что вы туда спрятали — ваши
> «прятанья» (далее по тексту будет использоваться это слово).

<sub>[цитата отсюда](https://pingvinus.ru/git/1718)</sub>

---

Далее, когда придёт время опять поработать над задачей в test1 нужно будет туда перейти и сделать `git stash apply`

> Команда git stash apply берет самое свежее прятанье (stash@{0}) и
> применяет его к репозиторию. То есть изменения, которые находятся в
> этом прятанье, применяются к текущему репозиторию.

> Если вы хотите применить какое-нибудь конкретное прятанье, можно
> указать его идентификатор:
>
> git stash apply stash@{1}

<sub>[цитата отсюда](https://pingvinus.ru/git/1718)</sub>

---

Собственно, это всё, что нужно знать, если хочется переключиться на другую задачу и ветку, а в текущей ветке не хочется делать коммит по какой-либо причине и нужно
временно спрятать данные, над которыми работал

---

- Документация по "прятанью" на руссском: [https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/Инструменты-Git-Припрятывание-и-очистка#r_git_stashing](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0#r_git_stashing)
- Документация по "прятанью" на  английском: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash
- Очень подробно и на русском от Atlassian - https://www.atlassian.com/ru/git/tutorials/saving-changes/git-stash
- Сторонний источник по прятанью на русском: https://pingvinus.ru/git/1718

---

##### Для PHPStorm

Всё ещё проще. У него Есть даже UI для работы со Stash. Пункты меню могут отличаться от версии к версии, я покажу на примере 2018:

Чтобы спрятать:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и даже можно ввести опознавательный знак:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**А потом достать изменения**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и выбрать нужные

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Вариант с `git stash` уже описали. Если приходится делать такое с несколькими ветками, то мне лично удобней сделать временный commit, так как со `stash` неочевидно, что из сохраненного к какой ветке относится.

Потом, после возвращения к ветке, есть два варианта:

1. отменить коммит, вернув все изменения в локальную копию, как все было до коммита, командой `git reset HEAD~1`. Эта команда удаляет последний коммит из репозитория, а изменения в нем сделанные переносит в локальную копию.
2. изменить коммит созданный ранее, добавив в него новые изменения, командой `git commit --amend`. Для этого делаем еще изменения в локальной копии, а потом `git commit --amend` добавляет эти изменения к последнему коммиту в текущей ветке.